# LeetCode Divide Two Integers - Repeated Exponential Searches solution with negative numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am having hard time understanding below solution in leetcode. Why int powerOfTwo = -1 is initialized with -1 as we have already handled divide(INT_MIN, -1) case
:
Adding problem statement -

Given two integers dividend and divisor, divide two integers without using multiplication, division, and mod operator.

Return the quotient after dividing dividend by divisor.

The integer division should truncate toward zero, which means losing its fractional part. For example, truncate(8.345) = 8 and truncate(-2.7335) = -2.

Note:

Assume we are dealing with an environment that could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2^31,  2^31 − 1]. For this problem, assume that your function returns 2^31 − 1 when the division result overflows.

Example 1:

Input: dividend = 10, divisor = 3
Output: 3
Explanation: 10/3 = truncate(3.33333..) = 3.

https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-two-integers/solution/

```
private static int HALF_INT_MIN = -1073741824;

public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    // Special case: overflow.
    if (dividend == Integer.MIN_VALUE && divisor == -1) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    /* We need to convert both numbers to negatives.
     * Also, we count the number of negatives signs. */
    int negatives = 2;
    if (dividend > 0) {
        negatives--;
        dividend = -dividend;
    }
    if (divisor > 0) {
        negatives--;
        divisor = -divisor;
    }

    int quotient = 0;
    /* Once the divisor is bigger than the current dividend,
     * we can't fit any more copies of the divisor into it. */
    while (divisor >= dividend) {
        /* We know it'll fit at least once as divivend >= divisor.
         * Note: We use a negative powerOfTwo as it's possible we might have
         * the case divide(INT_MIN, -1). */
        int powerOfTwo = -1;
        int value = divisor;
        /* Check if double the current value is too big. If not, continue doubling.
         * If it is too big, stop doubling and continue with the next step */
        while (value >= HALF_INT_MIN && value + value >= dividend) {
            value += value;
            powerOfTwo += powerOfTwo;
        }
        // We have been able to subtract divisor another powerOfTwo times.
        quotient += powerOfTwo;
        // Remove value so far so that we can continue the process with remainder.
        dividend -= value;
    }

    /* If there was originally one negative sign, then
     * the quotient remains negative. Otherwise, switch
     * it to positive. */
    if (negatives != 1) {
        return -quotient;
    }
    return quotient;
}
```

Comment: Please also explain the problem that the code is for. Your link only works for premium users of leetcode.

Comment: @ManuelRenePaulsToews Sure. Added in original post. Thanks